# Alternative to incron in Photon OS

Tags: cron

I'm setting up a server with Photon OS. I need to get a notification everytime a file is modified. I used `incrontab` in former Ubuntu Server setups, but this utility is not available in Photon OS repositories.

Provided I can compile it or create an script to check if the file was modified, I would like if there is an alternative or a way to install `incrontab` in Photon OS.

Thanks

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/vmware/photon/issues/554) you can install `cron` via command:

```
tdnf install cronie
```